# Is the app theme composable necessary to implement a custom theme in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-theme

Based on the MaterialTheme class as well as the android google code sample for themes in compose https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/e840fb90607069eb431f68d5291f03f4001bbd3d/Jetsnack we always see themes to have 2 parts:

The object theme:

```
object MaterialTheme {

val colors: Colors
    @Composable
    @ReadOnlyComposable
    get() = LocalColors.current

    ...
}
```

The composable theme:

```
fun MaterialTheme(
    colors: Colors = MaterialTheme.colors,
    typography: Typography = MaterialTheme.typography,
    shapes: Shapes = MaterialTheme.shapes,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val rememberedColors = remember {
        colors.copy()
    }.apply { updateColorsFrom(colors) }
    val selectionColors = rememberTextSelectionColors(rememberedColors)
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalColors provides rememberedColors,
        ...
    ) {
        ProvideTextStyle(value = typography.body1, content = content)
    }
}
```

Object theme -> We use the object every time we want to get a themed resource such as colour, typography... And when we do so we get access to the current theme value at the call site position in the composable hierarchy.

Composable theme -> By wrapping our content in the the composable theme, we can trigger recompositions in case our colors, shapes... etc change. Like changing from light to dark theme during runtime, or if in a certain screen you want to change a shapes for all composables inside it (below in the composable hierarchy).

However, when our app has a fixed set of colors (no dark theme), types and shapes that will not change, is there any point in applying the composable theme? Wouldn't it be a simpler app-theme-set-up to just use the object? Or is the whole point of the theme in compose to handle these dynamic changes?

Comment: One advantage, in addition to changing the theme dynamically, is that colors and other object parameters can be used as defaults, and that is how they are used in most material components such as `Buttons`, `TextField`, etc. If you don't provide any theme, and don't specify parameters manually, these components will use the default theme.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I see, so if i go to the `TextField` and `Button` classes, all the `MaterialTheme.xxx.yyy` will still work without a wrapper theme, but all the properties that access `LocalProperty.current` (where Property is TextStyle, Colors, Shapes... ) will look for a default in the wrapper theme, and then fall back to their own default values if they dont find anything? In `TextField`, `textStyle: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current` style would change if not wrapped in a theme, but `shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small` wouldn't be affected right? @PhilipDukhov

Comment: `LocalTextStyle` can be provided by some views, for example inside `Button` content it'll be `MaterialTheme.typography.button`. Material elements can have some tricky definition of style, especially when you see `Color.Unspecified` as a default value, but you can see the logic in the source code.